# Dovecot missed permissions to access mail directory

Tags: postfix, dovecot, file-permissions

I'm trying to install a new mail server and I think I've done something completly wrong. I don't know how to fix/continue my current situation.

I've installed postfix on my Debian 11 system, working with virtual mailboxes.
After that I installed Dovecot and configured it so that it get's access to the virtual mailboxes. But each time I receive a message, I get a message like this:

```
Jul 26 09:26:34 vps2412004 dovecot: imap(myuser)<31563><fGP3dV4BMvNSh3xC>: Error: Mailbox INBOX: open(/home/virtualmailboxes/myuser/cur/1690356394.V805I40085aM26143.vps24.fastwebserver.de:2,) failed: Permission denied (euid=1000(myuser) egid=100(users) missing +r perm: /home/virtualmailboxes/myuser/cur/1690356394.V805I40085aM26143.vps24.fastwebserver.de:2,, dir owned by 2000:2000 mode=0777)
Jul 26 09:26:34 vps2412004 dovecot: imap(myuser)<31563><fGP3dV4BMvNSh3xC>: FETCH failed: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2023-07-26 09:26:34] in=1499 out=336865 deleted=0 expunged=0 tra
```

When I look at the file, I see this:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 virtualmail virtualmail 324672 Jul 26 09:26 /home/virtualmailboxes/myuser/cur/1690356394.V805I40085aM26143.vps24.fastwebserver.de:2,
```

What do I have to do so Dovecot can access new mails properly? Right now I have a workaround (cronjob with chmod) working which can't be the real deal...

Please help!!

PS: I'm a newby...

Comment: Is the dovecot user a member of the virtualmail group?

Comment: yes, user "dovecot", "dovenull", "virtualmail" and "myuser" are members of the group "virtualmail" with the group id 2000.